# Multiple Custom Post Type permalink issue

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have 2 Custom Post Type(Our Works and Case Study) in a WordPress site. If I add same postname(Pepsi) at my 2 Custom Post Type(Our Works and Case Study) the permalink will show given below:

1) www.example.com/our-works/pepsi/

2) www.example.com/case-study/pepsi-2/

But It should be like:

1) www.example.com/our-works/pepsi/

2) www.example.com/case-study/pepsi/

Comment: There is a open ticket about this issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks cybmeta I have installed a plugin called [Allow Duplicate Slugs By John Blackbourn](https://github.com/johnbillion/allow-duplicate-slugs) and fixed issue! also I come across another [function.php solution](http://www.cuberis.com/2013/07/wordpress-duplicate-slugs-for-different-post-types/) too.